# Getting :after to add underline only under text and not the entire container

Tags: html, css, underline

I am wanting titles underlined with the `:after` method. I am getting it to work partially. What I cannot figure out is how to get the underline (`"after`) to only be under the span text inside of the `.slantTitleWrap`.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```css
.slantBlock2Title {
  color: #4D4D4D;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.slantTitleWrap span:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: #b82222;
  height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slantTitleWrap">
  <span class="slantBlock2Title">Uderline me</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Just curious -- rather than a `span:after` I probably would have done this with a `border-bottom` and possibly `padding-bottom` for desired spacing; for example `.slantBlock2Title { border-bottom: 2px solid #b82222; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by  using `display: inline-block`.

```css
.slantBlock2Title {
  color: #4D4D4D;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.slantTitleWrap span:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: #b82222;
  height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slantTitleWrap">
  <span class="slantBlock2Title">Uderline me</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I only added the `position`s to make it work like you wanted:

```css
.slantBlock2Title {
  position: relative;  /* Added */
  color: #4D4D4D;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.slantTitleWrap span:after {
  position: absolute;  /* Added */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%; /* Modified */
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: #b82222;
  height: 2px;
}

p{
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="slantTitleWrap">
  <span class="slantBlock2Title">U<u>n</u>derline me</span>
</div>
<br>
<p>(I added the “n”, too! :D)</p>
```

Hope it helps!